Css alignment in native base?

/* eslint-disable keyword-spacing */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
//import { background } from 'native-base/lib/typescript/theme/styled-system';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
//import {Container} from 'native-base';
//import { color } from "react-native-reanimated";
import AppInput from '../../Common/AppInput';
import AppButton from '../../Common/AppButton';
import { Checkbox } from 'native-base';

const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    function handleLogin() {
        console.log('login');
    }
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            <Text style={headingTitle}>LOGIN</Text>
            <AppInput
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={email}
                setValue={setEmail}
                secureTextEntry={true} />
            <AppInput
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                value={password}
                setValue={setPassword}
                secureTextEntry={true} />
            <AppButton
                onPress={handleLogin}
                title="Login"
            />
            <Checkbox value="test" accessibilityLabel="This is a dummy checkbox" />
            <Text style={text}>Remember me</Text>
            <Text style={text} >Forgot Password?</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const containerStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    //flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 30,
};

const headingTitle = {
    fontSize: 32,
    color: '#4b6798',
    margin: 30,
};

const text = {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 12,
};

export default Login;


this is Login Component
-------------------------
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'native-base';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

const AppInput = ({value, setValue, placeholder, secureTextEntry}) => {
  return (
      <Input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        setValue={setValue}
        secureTextEntry = {secureTextEntry}
        style= {inputStyle}
      />
  );
};

const containerStyle = {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
};

const inputStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    width: '100%',
    borderColor: '#c8eaf3',
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 2,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    //marginVertical: 5,
};

export default AppInput;
this is input common component
------------------------------
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
// MyButton.js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import { color } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const AppButton = ({ onPress, title }) => {
  return (
    <Button style={buttonStyle}
    onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>{title}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
};

const buttonStyle = {
  color: '#2895bc',
  width: '100%',
  padding: 20,
  borderRadius: 16,
}

const textStyle = {
  color: 'white', fontSize: 20,
}

export default AppButton;
this is common button component
-----------------------------

enter image description here
I have given all the written codes of this ui and I am trying to align these elements but the alignment is not working, I don't know why, kindly help me to fix this and also look into the code is it write way because this is the first time i am using native base, Thank You in advance.
